# Show a pdf file in laravel blade

Tags: html, jquery, laravel, pdf, laravel-blade

I am using laravel-7. I am making a job site,where applicant can upload resume (pdf) and company can view the pdf from laravel view page.
I uploaded the file successful. But I am unable to view the pdf in view page.

code:

```
 <td>
        {{$applicant_details->resume  }}
       
            <iframe src="{{asset('resume/'.$applicant_details->resume) }}" width=”100%” height=”100%”>
                This browser does not support PDFs. Please download the PDF to view it: Download PDF
                </iframe>
            
                <embed  src="{{asset('resume/'.$applicant_details->resume) }}" type=”application/pdf” width=”100%” height=”100%”>
    </td>
```

from {{$applicant_details->resume  }} I am getting the file name.

Tried both embed and iframe.
iframe gives a blank space.

embed says plugin not supported.

should I use jquery or something else?

Comment: Does your uploaded file is placed somewhere into public folder? What happen if you go to http://yourdomain.com/resume/fileName ?

Comment: please, do update your question with the complete path to the pdf. Code from the upload will also help, so we could see exactly what is happening.

Comment: yes, uploaded file is placed in public/resume folder @ElieMorin